# Why is the iPhone Simulator 3.0 not showing up in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I have installed the new 3.0 SDK, but when I start up Xcode, I don't see an option to build for "Device - iPhone OS 3.0" or "Simulator - iPhone OS 3.0"

The Xcode About box says I am running: 3.1.2

Is there something else I have to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to upgrade to Xcode 3.1.3.  I have the latest version and that's what my About box reads.

If you are sure you downloaded the latest version, perhaps you installed in to a different location?

Comment: I was stuck on 3.1.2, for some reason. Even after reinstalls. I had to remove Xcode from the application folder for it to reinstall. Lame.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an existing project you may have to tell your project to build to the 3.0 targets.  I didn't have to do this for any of my projects but ...

Under the Deployment section of your project properties you should see:

iPhone OS Deployment Target - (change this to use iPhone OS 3.0)

You can also check that the Architectures section has the Base SDK set to 3.0.

Comment: I don't have that choice there either.

Answer (score 0):

This happens quite often when downloading Apple's sample code projects which are targeted for iOS 3.x but you've got iOS 4.x.

To show Simulator option go to Project Info window -> General tab -> Base SDK for All Configurations - choose Latest iOS.

If it doesn't appear straight away, close and reopen Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

I clicked on the box (where I expected iPhone Simulator to be shown), right clicked manage scheme. After that deleted all schemes, and in similar way, created a new scheme. It automatically produced all simulators including the ones for devices.